# "Большая просьба ответить на письмо". Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

**Большая просьба ответить на письмо, ...**

Должны ли быть на этом отрезке текста знаки препинания?

Comment: Даже не могу предположить, где. А ваше-то какое мнение, где вы предполагаете возможность знака?

Comment: А, пардон, у Вас русский - не родной, наверное. Нет, знаков тут не надо.

Answer (score 2):

Большая просьба ответить на письмо, ...

Но: Большая просьба - ответить на это письмо.

**ПОЯСНЕНИЕ**

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса**

(1) Большая просьба дополнить мои аргументы, и где возможно, усилить. Большая просьба откликнуться.

(2) **Большая просьба - ответить на это письмо.** Большая просьба ― организовать Вашу встречу с представителями рыбаков, избранными вторым Всероссийским съездом.

(3) Но к вам большая просьба: никому об этом не говорить.

**Для постановки знаков препинания нужно определить грамматику  предложения. Можно предположить следующее:**

Вариант 1. Простое предложение: Большая просьба (= прошу о чём) ответить на письмо..., нет паузы и тире. Логическое ударение на инфинитиве.

Вариант 2. Та же конструкция, но с тире и паузой (в связи с большей распространенностью). Ударение и на первой, и на второй части предложения.

Вариант 3. Сложное предложение (БСП): второе предложение раскрывает содержание первого, первое предложение эллиптического типа, второе - безличное.